# What does it mean "orderby: other" in Dropbox SDK

Tags: node.js, dropbox-api, dropbox-sdk-js

I'm using dropbox api to search files in a connected account. I need to implement feature to sort search result by selected criteria. For example, I need sort files by last modifying time or by title (in alphabetical order). In dropbox documentation I found that I can filter result by date. But It's unclear to me if I can filter results by title.

There is an option called "other". I could not find any information about what does the "other" option mean.

Here is the link for dropbox api I found: https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/global.html#FilesSearchOrderBy

So here are my questions.

1. What does "other" option mean?
2. Can I sort files by last modified time using ASC and DESC ordering?

I'm using dropbox 5.2.1 so far.

Comment: it appears to mean "none" ... perhaps "none" is a reserved word

Answer (score 0):

The `other` tag indicates that the `FilesSearchOrderBy` object is an "open union", meaning more values may be added in the future. The `other` option doesn't indicate any more actual functional that can currently be accessed.

So, the only actual options are currently `relevance` and `last_modified_time`. This doesn't offer ascending/descending options. If you want to order by modified time, you should use `last_modified_time`, and reverse the results if they're not in the direction you want.